# Best way to implement a VR for Close Deals

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

We want to implement a VR that restrict users from making edits on Closed Opportunities, however, we want to grant access to some 'Finance' fields to our Finance Users once a deal is Closed.

What would be the best way to implement this?
Right now we have a VR that restrict any change, and we grant a permission set to users so they can make edits but to all fields. What I'm trying to avoid, is that we create a HUGE VR where we are telling the fields that can be used, and by what profiles. Not sure there is a way to avoid it

Comment: at some point in the hopefully near future, dynamic page layouts for standard objects will become possible and the recordtype/pagelayout solution will no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use Record Types and multiple Page Layouts. You can make *most* fields read-only by way of Page Layouts, so you'll only need a handful of validation rules in order to "lock" required fields (e.g. Opportunity Name). You can use an Automation (Workflow Rule, Process Builder, or Before Save Flow) to change the Record Type from the "open" layout to the "closed" layout when the Opportunity reaches a Closed state. By the way, each field *should* have its own Validation Rule; this allows the UI to highlight specific fields that have errors in them. Do not try to "save" Validation Rules by cramming a bunch of logic into one Validation Rule. This is a very poor User Experience.

Comment: Genius!! 
The part of automating the record type to Closed will do wonders for us. Thanks!